# Program/Applet for generating a Huffman Tree with given Frequencies

Tags: tree, applet, huffman-code, alphabet

I have been given the alphabet with its frequencies, like:

e: 17,4

n: 9,78

j: 0,27

and so on. For every letter of the alphabet.
My question is:

Is there any program/applet that generates me a huffman tree with these given frequencies? The only generators I have found do use Text as input.

Maybe one of you might have an idea! Thank you very much!

Comment: What does "17,4" mean?

Comment: These values are the relative frequencies of the letters. If you have a text with 1000 words, the letter e would exist 174 times in this text. My problem is that there are only programs who scan the text and then do count the frequency of the letter. But I have already been given these values...

Comment: Ah, so the comma must be a decimal point here.  The comma was confusing me at first, making me wonder what the numbers 17 and 4 represented.

Answer (score 1):

If you have source code that takes letters, computes their frequency, and then applies the Huffman algorithm, then you can simply strip the part that computes the frequency and use the Huffman algorithm directly on the frequencies.

Otherwise, you can write the Huffman algorithm yourself.  It is one of the simplest and most elegant algorithms out there, so everyone should implement it themselves at least once.  You sort the frequencies and pick the two lowest.  Those two symbols are joined as the first branch of the tree.  Reinsert the sum of the frequencies in the sorted list.  Repeat until all of the symbols are part of the tree.